Errors after apt-get upgrade from cron job
I run apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt autoremove from a cron job on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and on Tuesday I got this error:
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl libcurl3t64-gnutls libcurl4t64 libpython3.12-dev libpython3.12-minimal
  libpython3.12-stdlib libpython3.12t64 linux-libc-dev linux-tools-common
  nginx nginx-common python3.12 python3.12-dev python3.12-minimal
...
Get:13 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 nginx amd64 1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1 [521 kB]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 nginx-common all 1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1 [31.2 kB]
...
Preparing to unpack .../12-nginx_1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) over (1.24.0-2ubuntu7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-nginx-common_1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) over (1.24.0-2ubuntu7) ...
...
Setting up nginx (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) ...
 * Upgrading binary nginx
   ...done.
Setting up nginx-common (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
 installed nginx-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have tried to apt-get purge nginx* and reinstalling it, or apt-get install --reconfigure nginx, but it makes no difference.
I have tried /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst configure which results in Segmentation fault.
What can I do to fix this? Could using a different mirror than http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu fix this and how would I do that?
Here is the full log:
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble InRelease
Get:2 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Get:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]
Get:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Sources [255 kB]
Get:5 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted Sources [19.4 kB]
Get:6 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main i386 Packages [276 kB]
Get:7 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages [528 kB]
Get:8 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [127 kB]
Get:9 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [8,352 B]
Get:10 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [353 kB]
Get:11 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted Translation-en [68.1 kB]
Get:12 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Packages [368 kB]
Get:13 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/universe i386 Packages [160 kB]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/universe Translation-en [151 kB]
Get:15 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.3 kB]
Get:16 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/main Sources [97.2 kB]
Get:17 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/main i386 Packages [154 kB]
Get:18 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages [354 kB]
Get:19 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/main Translation-en [79.4 kB]
Get:20 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4,512 B]
Get:21 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/universe i386 Packages [104 kB]
Get:22 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 Packages [269 kB]
Get:23 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/universe Translation-en [113 kB]
Get:24 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [10.1 kB]
Fetched 3,766 kB in 1s (6,081 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl libcurl3t64-gnutls libcurl4t64 libpython3.12-dev libpython3.12-minimal
  libpython3.12-stdlib libpython3.12t64 linux-libc-dev linux-tools-common
  nginx nginx-common python3.12 python3.12-dev python3.12-minimal
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 python3.12-dev amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [498 kB]
Get:2 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 libpython3.12-dev amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [5,672 kB]
Get:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 libpython3.12t64 amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [2,339 kB]
Get:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 python3.12 amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [651 kB]
Get:5 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 libpython3.12-stdlib amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [2,069 kB]
Get:6 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 python3.12-minimal amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [2,343 kB]
Get:7 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 libpython3.12-minimal amd64 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2 [834 kB]
Get:8 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 [227 kB]
Get:9 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 libcurl4t64 amd64 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 [341 kB]
Get:10 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 libcurl3t64-gnutls amd64 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 [333 kB]
Get:11 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 6.8.0-45.45 [1,698 kB]
Get:12 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 linux-tools-common all 6.8.0-45.45 [540 kB]
Get:13 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 nginx amd64 1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1 [521 kB]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 nginx-common all 1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1 [31.2 kB]
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
Fetched 18.1 MB in 0s (80.8 MB/s)
(Reading database ... (Reading database ... 5%(Reading database ... 10%(Reading database ... 15%(Reading database ... 20%(Reading database ... 25%(Reading database ... 30%(Reading database ... 35%(Reading database ... 40%(Reading database ... 45%(Reading database ... 50%(Reading database ... 55%(Reading database ... 60%(Reading database ... 65%(Reading database ... 70%(Reading database ... 75%(Reading database ... 80%(Reading database ... 85%(Reading database ... 90%(Reading database ... 95%(Reading database ... 100%(Reading database ... 117484 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-python3.12-dev_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.12-dev (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libpython3.12-dev_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.12-dev:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libpython3.12t64_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.12t64:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-python3.12_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.12 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libpython3.12-stdlib_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.12-stdlib:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-python3.12-minimal_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.12-minimal (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libpython3.12-minimal_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.12-minimal:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) over (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-curl_8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4) over (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libcurl4t64_8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4t64:amd64 (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4) over (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libcurl3t64-gnutls_8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3t64-gnutls:amd64 (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4) over (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-linux-libc-dev_6.8.0-45.45_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.8.0-45.45) over (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-linux-tools-common_6.8.0-45.45_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (6.8.0-45.45) over (6.8.0-44.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-nginx_1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) over (1.24.0-2ubuntu7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-nginx-common_1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) over (1.24.0-2ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libcurl4t64:amd64 (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4) ...
Setting up libpython3.12-minimal:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libcurl3t64-gnutls:amd64 (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up curl (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4) ...
Setting up linux-tools-common (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up python3.12-minimal (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython3.12-stdlib:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python3.12 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython3.12t64:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython3.12-dev:amd64 (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python3.12-dev (3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up nginx (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) ...
 * Upgrading binary nginx
   ...done.
Setting up nginx-common (1.24.0-2ubuntu7.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
 installed nginx-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36.2-6) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (255.4-1ubuntu8.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have run strace -f apt-get install --reinstall nginx-common > log.strace-aptget 2>&1, which contains the following at the end:
close(5)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(4)                                = 0
write(1, "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1"..., 1770 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
) = 177
write(2, "E", 1E)                        = 1
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Internal Error, No file name for"..., 51Internal Error, No file name for nginx-common:amd64) = 51
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(100)                         = ?
+++ exited with 100 +++

I used strace to see what happens when reconfiguring dpkg:
strace -f dpkg-reconfigure --terse --force nginx-common -u > log.strace-dpkg-reconfigure 2>&1
Result (a segmentation fault):
[pid 1572352] <... execve resumed>)     = 0
[pid 1572352] brk(NULL)                 = 0x56d7d1e55000
[pid 1572352] mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x70164667e000
[pid 1572352] access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 1572352] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 1572352] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=41167, ...}) = 0
[pid 1572352] mmap(NULL, 41167, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x701646673000
[pid 1572352] close(4)                  = 0
[pid 1572352] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 1572352] read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\243\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
[pid 1572352] pread64(4, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
[pid 1572352] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2125328, ...}) = 0
[pid 1572352] pread64(4, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
[pid 1572352] mmap(NULL, 2170256, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x701646400000
[pid 1572352] mmap(0x701646428000, 1605632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x28000) = 0x701646428000
[pid 1572352] mmap(0x7016465b0000, 323584, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x1b0000) = 0x7016465b0000
[pid 1572352] mmap(0x7016465ff000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x1fe000) = 0x7016465ff000
[pid 1572352] mmap(0x701646605000, 52624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x701646605000
[pid 1572352] close(4)                  = 0
[pid 1572352] mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x701646670000
[pid 1572352] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x701646670740) = 0
[pid 1572352] set_tid_address(0x701646670a10) = 1572352
[pid 1572352] set_robust_list(0x701646670a20, 24) = 0
[pid 1572352] rseq(0x701646671060, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
[pid 1572352] mprotect(0x7016465ff000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 1572352] mprotect(0x56d7d0e65000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 1572352] mprotect(0x7016466b6000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 1572352] prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
[pid 1572352] munmap(0x701646673000, 41167) = 0
[pid 1572352] getrandom("\x55\x7e\xab\xab\x0d\x75\x57\x7c", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
[pid 1572352] brk(NULL)                 = 0x56d7d1e55000
[pid 1572352] brk(0x56d7d1e76000)       = 0x56d7d1e76000
[pid 1572352] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 1572352] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5719296, ...}) = 0
[pid 1572352] mmap(NULL, 5719296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x701645e00000
[pid 1572352] close(4)                  = 0
[pid 1572352] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x1} ---
[pid 1572352] +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
[pid 1572350] <... wait4 resumed>[{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV}], 0, NULL) = 1572352
[pid 1572350] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=1572352, si_uid=0, si_status=SIGSEGV, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---

Running strace -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst configure > log.strace-postinst 2>&1 results in:
[pid 1576293] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid 1576293] execve("/usr/bin/chown", ["chown", "root:adm", "/var/log/nginx"], 0x5b4075992a08 /* 42 vars */ <unfinished ...>
[pid 1576291] <... vfork resumed>)      = 1576293
[pid 1576291] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid 1576291] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 1576293] <... execve resumed>)     = 0
[pid 1576293] brk(NULL)                 = 0x5d1938564000
[pid 1576293] mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x732eb9337000
[pid 1576293] access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 1576293] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 1576293] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=41167, ...}) = 0
[pid 1576293] mmap(NULL, 41167, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x732eb932c000
[pid 1576293] close(4)                  = 0
[pid 1576293] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 1576293] read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\243\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
[pid 1576293] pread64(4, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
[pid 1576293] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2125328, ...}) = 0
[pid 1576293] pread64(4, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
[pid 1576293] mmap(NULL, 2170256, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x732eb9000000
[pid 1576293] mmap(0x732eb9028000, 1605632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x28000) = 0x732eb9028000
[pid 1576293] mmap(0x732eb91b0000, 323584, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x1b0000) = 0x732eb91b0000
[pid 1576293] mmap(0x732eb91ff000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x1fe000) = 0x732eb91ff000
[pid 1576293] mmap(0x732eb9205000, 52624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x732eb9205000
[pid 1576293] close(4)                  = 0
[pid 1576293] mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x732eb9329000
[pid 1576293] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x732eb9329740) = 0
[pid 1576293] set_tid_address(0x732eb9329a10) = 1576293
[pid 1576293] set_robust_list(0x732eb9329a20, 24) = 0
[pid 1576293] rseq(0x732eb932a060, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
[pid 1576293] mprotect(0x732eb91ff000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 1576293] mprotect(0x5d19380cf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 1576293] mprotect(0x732eb936f000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 1576293] prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
[pid 1576293] munmap(0x732eb932c000, 41167) = 0
[pid 1576293] getrandom("\x1b\x2d\xd9\x4d\x1b\xff\x88\xa9", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
[pid 1576293] brk(NULL)                 = 0x5d1938564000
[pid 1576293] brk(0x5d1938585000)       = 0x5d1938585000
[pid 1576293] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 1576293] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5719296, ...}) = 0
[pid 1576293] mmap(NULL, 5719296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x732eb8a00000
[pid 1576293] close(4)                  = 0
[pid 1576293] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x1} ---
[pid 1576293] +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
[pid 1576291] <... wait4 resumed>[{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV}], 0, NULL) = 1576293
[pid 1576291] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=1576293, si_uid=0, si_status=SIGSEGV, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 1576291] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})   = 1576293
[pid 1576291] write(2, "Segmentation fault\n", 19Segmentation fault
) = 19
[pid 1576291] wait4(-1, 0x7fff8871a49c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
[pid 1576291] exit_group(139)           = ?
[pid 1576291] +++ exited with 139 +++


You may want to do DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y upgrade to prevent debconf from trying to talk to the non-existent terminal.  Or look at the unattended process options; https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Also, since you get (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.), try running TERM=xterm-256color apt-get -y upgrade in case that fixes it.

Running apt-get from a non-interactive environment is unreliable, as far too many packages try to ask interactive questions even when told not to.  I still don't know why kernel updates try to run plymouth.

Adding TERM=xterm-256color doesn't help. I think I will go back to manually upgrading, rather than doing it automatically. But I still have the problem that I get errors after upgrading, or for every new package that I add.

DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y upgrade didnt help either

I updated the script at /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst to include some echo statements and worked out that it was failing on the line chown root:adm $logdir, which really made no sense, as I was running as root.
So, ... I rebooted... and now the problem is fixed. I re-ran apt-get upgrade and there are no more errors.
Grrrr...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UT8RkSmN4k :-)

had even more problems today, docker didn't work anymore, and uninstalling and reinstalling threw a load of perl errors. again, restarted and all was well. VERY STRANGE side effects.
